# How can I get text from a "span" tag using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to find the text `Ron LaVine's Connect to Influencers and Decision Makers`. But I am having trouble doing so. I need this in order to find a link to the author's name on the page. I do not want to hard code author's in the program so I am wondering what I need to do in order to get the text. I used this XPath:

```xml
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[1]/span[2]
```

and then used `getText()` but that did not work.

```
<div class="ytp-title">
    <a class="ytp-title-channel-logo" target="_blank"></a>
    <div class="ytp-title-text">
        <a class="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink" target="_blank" data-sessionlink="feature=player-title" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L6h5ug2QJI">
            <span class="ytp-title-playlist-icon" style="display: none;">
                <svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" width="100%">
            </span>
            <span>Ron LaVine's Connect to Influencers and Decision Makers</span>
        </a>
```

Comment: There is no way we can verify the xpath if we don't see the full html code and it's difficult to see programming errors if we don't see the java code.

Comment: The full html is very large and it would not make sense to post it here.   As for the code it was pretty basic, I have already removed it for now.   But it used the xpath I show in the question and then I used the .getText() method.   All I need to know is from what I supplied what can I use to get that text apparently it is not using the xpath directly to that span tag.   I wish I could provide more information but at this point that is all I have.   I know the xpath to that is correct since I used Firebug to generate it.   SO you do not need to verify that.

Comment: what does `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[1]/span[2]")).getText();` return ?

Comment: Can you show us what `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Influencers and Decision Makers')]"));` return?

Comment: Nothing.   It does not return anything at all.

Comment: Post a link to the page so we can help find an answer. The first span is hidden, have you tried `.../span[1]` in your XPath? Having an XPath that is that long or starts from the HTML tag is not a good idea. It's prone to break.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the answer from a group I belong to on Facebook.    Actually ended up using List  we5 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sqs-block-content']/p//a"));